# Can not login as newly created MySQL user

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am working on a project for a client, and instead of using my usual 'root' SQL password, I needed to create a new User/Password with specific access rights. I looke up how to do this and found that I should use the following:

```
CREATE USER 'AppSrv'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON some_db.* TO 'AppSrv'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

When I run `select * from mysql.user;` I can see that the user has been added to the table, however when using PDO or PHPMyAdmin I get an error stating: `Access denied for user 'AppSrv'@'localhost'`

I have created users in the past without a problem, and am not sure why it is now not working. I have attempted rebooting the SQL server as well with no avail.

Running:

> Linux version 3.2.0-24-virtual (buildd@crested) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) )
>   MySQL v5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.3 - (Ubuntu)

What could be a possible fix to create new users for my SQL Server?

**EDIT**

I have also tried using PHPMyAdmin to create the user, and even that fails when trying to login.

Comment: See the edit to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the account with @'localhost':

```
CREATE USER 'AppSrv'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON some_db.* TO 'AppSrv'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Otherwise the anonymous-user account for localhost that is created by mysql_install_db would take precedence - see mysql doc [adding users](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html) or [access denied](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/access-denied.html)

Comment: I am still getting the same error: `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'AppSrv'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Comment: seems you have not updated first part of query? `CREATE USER 'AppSrv'@'localhost'`

Comment: Well... I rebooted the server again... and now that works and I can login... Shouldn't '%' accept any host, including 'localhost'? Why would just a '%' not work..?

Comment: The '%' does match localhost.  Try executing 'FLUSH PRIVILEGES' instead.

Comment: I was under the impression that '%' was a wildcard that match anything including localhost, but I guess not. Well, Problem solved by using 'localhost' instead of '%'. Thanks!